# How to run vb.net project in another pc?

Tags: vb.net, deployment

Please help i've done many research but all failed when i tried to install my vb.net project to another pc with no vb.net. the installer says:

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers Version 10.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

but i can't find a good tut on how to solve this error. I'm a beginner in deploying .Net projects. Please someone help me i need it tomorrow to work on another pc. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i think it have some other way for installing. I also having installed issue since before. But i tried other way. If your project don't need licensing and just like free open sources, you can tried install by ZIP. You can check ZIP installer. This [link](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/39048-how-to-make-a-7-zip-switchless-installer/)will teach you. Also you just need copy your debug folder as installer item

```
copy /b 7z.sfx + config.txt + file_name.7z setupname.exe >> This line we write at cmd
```

7z.sfx is a file from C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.sfx<< This you copy to your new dir
file_name.7z << Your dir that want to install to other computer and you zip it
Setupname.exe << This is your own name for the exe but must same with Config.txt

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
RunProgram="REgFile.exe .cmd"
;!@InstallEnd@! << All this is config.txt text
```

You must change the RegFile.exe to your setupname.exe name
.cmd is basic for our coppy

Comment: i followed the tut but when im about to install it on another pc there's error saying "The system cannot find the path specified" what is the meaning of this?

Comment: Let me explain to you  for the CMD string,, i will edit my answer